# .htaccess - How to use request HTTP header value in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm wondering how to get 
**HTTP Header referer**

- and if the value is set
- redirect to another domain with this value as  **Query string** param **utm_source**

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

This is solution

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampleFrom.cz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Referer} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampleTo.cz/$1?utm_source=%{HTTP:Referer} [L,R=301]
```

solution is with parsed domain from referer

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.exampleFrom.cz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Referer}  ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampleTo.cz/$1?utm_source=%1&utm_medium=referal&utm_campaign=myDomainCampaign [L,R=301]
```